# Is there a way that the bot can add a reaction to a user's message command?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
@commands.command(name='clear', aliases=['clean', 'cleanup'])
  async def clear(self, ctx, limit: int = 10) -> None:
          messages = await ctx.channel.purge(bulk=True, limit=limit)
          embed=discord.Embed(title=f"`{len(messages)}` mensagens deletadas com sucesso", color=COR_PRINCIPAL)
          embed.set_author(name="Plugin de comandos do Tatrantolo",icon_url=ICONE)
          await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=5)
```

I want the bot to add a reaction, probably a ckeck emoji to the user's command, showing that the command was received. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you check the documentation? Did you try putting `discord.py react to command` into a search engine? I got [this result](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/discussions/5877).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to add this before the end of your command in the main indentation probably.

```py
await ctx.message.add_reaction("✅")
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize it was that simple, thank you so much!!!